# Rxswift how to call 1 or more functions in return of the other function

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have used RxSwift to call other function in the return of the first function. For that I have tried this code:

```
func startSyncNow(_ call: CAPPluginCall,lastSyncTime: String) -> Observable<String> {
         return   createOrAlterTable(call)

            .flatMapLatest(){ query -> Observable<String> in
                let formschema = self.formSchemaToSQLite(call, lastSyncTime: lastSyncTime)
               return formschema
        }.flatMapLatest(){ query -> Observable<String> in
            let menuTable = self.menuTableRecord(call, lastSyncTime: lastSyncTime)
               return menuTable
        }
        .map { query -> String in
            return "Success"
       }
    }
    
    func  createOrAlterTable(_ call: CAPPluginCall) -> Observable<[[String:Any]]>{
    
     return Observable.just("Sucess")
    }
    
    func formSchemaToSQLite(_ call: CAPPluginCall,lastSyncTime : String) -> Observable<String> {
        return Observable.just("Sucess")
    }
    
    
    func menuTableRecord(_ call: CAPPluginCall,lastSyncTime:String) -> Observable<String>{
        return Observable.just("Sucess")
    }
```

When I am debugging this code, I am not able to hit debug point on either formSchemaToSQLite or recordsTOSqlite. Please guide me what I am missing

Comment: You need to subscribe to the Observable.

Comment: @DanielT.  can  you  please  share  piece of  code  which  will  work   ,i  have   tried in  subscribing  but  having  comiler  error

Comment: I'm happy to post a working example. First I will need you to provide sample code that compiles though. Your sample code above doesn't compile.

Comment: @DanielT,here  is  the  code  which  will  compile   ,```

Comment: It still won't compile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following both compiles and when you call the `example()` function, all the functions are called:

```
struct CAPPluginCall { }

func example() {
    _ = startSyncNow(CAPPluginCall(), lastSyncTime: "before")
        .subscribe(onNext: { result in
            print(result)
        })
}

func startSyncNow(_ call: CAPPluginCall, lastSyncTime: String) -> Observable<String> {
    return createOrAlterTable(call)
        .flatMapLatest { query -> Observable<String> in
            let formschema = formSchemaToSQLite(call, lastSyncTime: lastSyncTime)
            return formschema
        }
        .flatMapLatest { query -> Observable<String> in
            let menuTable = menuTableRecord(call, lastSyncTime: lastSyncTime)
            return menuTable
        }
        .map { query -> String in
            return "Success"
        }
}

func createOrAlterTable(_ call: CAPPluginCall) -> Observable<[[String:Any]]>{
    return Observable.just([[:]])
}

func formSchemaToSQLite(_ call: CAPPluginCall,lastSyncTime : String) -> Observable<String> {
    return Observable.just("Sucess")
}


func menuTableRecord(_ call: CAPPluginCall,lastSyncTime:String) -> Observable<String>{
    return Observable.just("Sucess")
}
```